# web3Modal not installing

Tags: ethers.js, wallet-connect, web3modal

I keep getting an error when trying to install a specific version of web3modal on my Dapp, no matter the version i try to install it doesn't work.

```
npm install web3modal@1.9.12
```

When i enter this in my terminal i keep getting this error;

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve       
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: @nomicfoundation/hardhat-chai-matchers@2.0.2
npm ERR! Found: ethers@5.7.2
npm ERR! node_modules/ethers
npm ERR!   ethers@"^5.7.1" from @nomicfoundation/ethereumjs-block@5.0.2
```

These are just some of the errors that keep getting returned to me. I can't paste them all here.

I tried installing the latest version as it is in the web3modal docs,

```
npm install web3modal
```

But i still got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I had that same error but was able to solve mine by uninstall a package called @nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox

If you have it installed please uninstall it by running( npm uninstall @nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox ) and try install npm install web3modal and npm install --save-dev @nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox@2 again, this time it should install

The reason you were getting the error is because the version ^5 of ethers requires version ^2 of @nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox while version ^6 of ethers requires version ^3 of @nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox

If run into any issue please share it and let's see how we can solve it together.